# Classpath error while configuring grails on Windows

Tags: grails

I want to install grails on my windows 10 (x64). The grails version I have is 3.3.4, groovy version 2.4.14, JVM version 1.8.0_141. I can create an app but when I run it an error comes out:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'hello'.  
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.  
Could not resolve org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:3.3.4.  
Required :  
project :
Could not resolve org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:3.3.4.  
Could not get resource 'https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/grails-gradle-plugin/3.3.4/grails-gradle-plugin-3.3.4.pom'.  
Could not GET 'https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/grails-gradle-plugin/3.3.4/grails-gradle-plugin-3.3.4.pom'.  
Connect to repo.grails.org:443 [repo.grails.org/198.18.1.217] failed: Connection timed out: connect  
Could not resolve org.grails.plugins:hibernate5:6.1.9.  
Required by:  
project :  
Could not resolve org.grails.plugins:hibernate5:6.1.9.  
Could not get resource  
'https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/hibernate5/6.1.9/hibernate5-6.1.9.pom'.  
Could not GET  'https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/hibernate5/6.1.9/hibernate5-6.1.9.pom'.  
Connect to repo.grails.org:443 [repo.grails.org/198.18.1.217] failed: Connection timed out: connect  

Try:  
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

CONFIGURE FAILED

Total time: 1 mins 4.547 secs
Error Error initializing classpath: Connection timed out: connect (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

I have searched everywhere but haven't found a solution. Please help me to resolve this.

PS: Every time I try to run the app, strangely the net becomes unbelievably slow.

Comment: Improved readability

Comment: Looks like this is internet connection issue- the application is not able to download dependencies.  You may try downloading the dependencies first using-    grails refresh-dependencies

Comment: try to do that but still no changes here's what i type :

Comment: c:\grails>grails refresh-dependencies  
Usage:  
         create-app [NAME] --profile=web  
         create-plugin [NAME] --profile=web-plugin  


| Available Profiles  
--------------------
* angular - A profile for creating Grails applications with Angular 5+  
* rest-api - Profile for REST API applications  
* base - The base profile extended by other profiles